# Generate JSON from table

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I'm looking for help about generating a JSON file from an source imported (for my case an other json file).

Begining I've sucessfully imported my Json content :

```
$Rules = get-content .\output.json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -expand Rules
```

My source JSON is like that :

```
{
 Id               : rslvr-autodefined    
 Name             : myName1    
 ShareStatus      : NOT_SHARED
}
{
Id                 : rslvr-rr-ea6e4ec113014e1fb    
Name               : myName2    
ShareStatus        : SHARED_WITH_ME
}
```

For this post I shrink my source file with 2 items (myName1 & myName2) but I can have more than 2 ID.

Goal is to generate an other JSON with this format:

```
"Resources": {

        "myName1": {

            "Type": "This is my type",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "myName1",
                "RuleId": "rslvr-autodefined",
                "Destination": "this is my fixed destination"
            },

            "Metadata": {
                
            }
        },
        "myName2": {

            "Type": "This is my type",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "myName2",
                "RuleId": "rslvr-rr-ea6e4ec113014e1fb    ",
                "Destination": "this is my fixed destination"
            },

            "Metadata": {
                
            }
        },
    }
```

What I coded is :

```
$Rules = get-content .\output.json | ConvertFrom-Json | select -expand Rules  
foreach($myRule in $Rules) {    
$Json= @{
    Resources = @{
        $myRule.Name = [Ordered]@{            
        Type= "This is my type"
        Properties = @(
            @{
                Name=$myRule.Name
                RuleId = $myRule.Id
                "Destination": "this is my fixed destination"
            }               
        )            
        }
    }    
}
}
$Json |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```

With this code I sucessfully a JSON but it only contains One ressource and not all contained in my source file, and I don't know how to increment and add "x" ressources in my JSON structure...

Could you help me ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `$Json` variable with each iteration of your loop.
If I'm understanding your desired format correctly, you would need to do something like this:

```
$JsonRules = foreach ($myRule in $Rules) {
    $myRule.Name = [Ordered]@{
        Type       = "This is my type"
        Properties = @{
            Name = $myRule.Name
            RuleId = $myRule.Id
            Destination = "this is my fixed destination"
        }
    }
}
@{ Resources = $JsonRules } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
```